# Is this some version of loosestrife?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

[image: What is this?]

This is growing in a sunny yard in a planter in Northeastern Illinois near the Wisconsin border. It's growing in a planter that should be butterfly-friendly specific. Don't want to yank it if it's beneficial; it's pretty darn healthy!

Comment: Nevermind. Figured out it was pokeberry. Thanks!

Comment: I added also an *official* answer.

Comment: Kat, the flower does look like Gooseneck Loosestrife.  One of my all time favorite plants!  But pokeberry is a cool plant and I am curious as to how it got in your planter?  Did you use garden soil for this planter?

Answer (score 5):

It is *Phytolacca americana* (pokeweed).  It will become very tall. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana.